# Magnific vs PhotoSwipe

Tags: magnific-popup, photoswipe

I'm sure this question has been asked and answered before but I can't find it so I apologize in advance.

Since Dmitry is the author of both and the look very similar, I'm wondering what the major differences are and why I should might choose one over the other.  They both look great!

Comment: Magnific was designed to show any kind of content (forms, videos, etc.) and more suitable for web apps. PhotoSwipe is just for images.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry!  You rock!

Answer (score 1):

PhotoSwipe : You can swipe through images.
Magnific : You use buttons to go through images.

PhotoSwipe seems to be more up-to-date with current technologies and also the design is better than Magnific.

Personally I would choose PhotoSwipe.